# Concatenate text with newlines in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

If I have a column in a table where each cell contains text, how can I push them as output into e.g. a card and separate the cells with a new line?

I have been using the `CONCATENATEX` function, which takes a delimiter argument; however the standard new line character (`'\n'`) doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to pass Unicode characters to the `CONCATENATEX` function, using the `UNICHAR(number)` function.

The `number` parameter corresponds what looks to be the decimal UTF-16 or UTF-32 encodings (as shown [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm)).

This means a new line is given by `UNICHAR(10)`.

A final solution might then be: `CONCATENATEX(TableName, TableName[TextColumn], UNICHAR(10))`

Here is a screenshot that shows:

- the input table in Excel (top left)
- The table once imported into Power BI Desktop (top right)
- The Measure 'Description' and the output within a Card object (bottom)

[image]

In the last line of the Measure code, marked yellow, you can see the use of `UNICHAR(10)` as a new line separator.

If nothing were to be selected in the Slicer object (i.e. everything is selected by default - no filter is used), then "Show other text" would be displayed in the Card.

Comment: Amazing. Which release of PowerBI is this? I still can't get that to work. Is there some formatting setting that you need to adjust?

Comment: It is the latest release - October 2017. Although I didn't see anything in the Release Notes that made me think it would only now be possible. I haven't tried it in earlier version. Regarding format settings: I didn't perform any sorcery - it all comes from the code that is visible in the screenshot  :)

Comment: Okay, as soon as I install October 2017 now it works. We learned something!

Comment: Currently, the UNICODE function is not working as explained above. You can find a solution and example for this question in the following link:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-get-text-in-new-line-in-the-data-cards-label/m-p/441556/highlight/true#M203915

Comment: Very nice little trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the concatenate code, if you insert a "shift + enter" after the comma, it gives me a line break, without breaking the code.

Example:

```
'Query1'[LetterCode],
 ",<Inserted SHIFT-ENTER here>
 ", 
'Query1'[LetterCode],
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute /n with the string "#(cr)#(lf)" to create a new line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33244565)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have addex more detail