# PowerBi - Two Measures to show in one card

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I was reviewing a video on line and the video had a card with two measures. I took a screenshot:

[image]

There is the main one: Total Sales and a sub measurement: Target sales. How can I get two measures into one card? So whoever is looking at this dashboard can see that the current total sales is this and the target is this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in you measure :

```
My_measure = 
var total_sales = *do some calculations*
var target_sales = *do some calculations* 

return 
total_sales & UNICHAR(10) & target_sales
```

You can also check this link
[Concatenate text with newlines in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705969/concatenate-text-with-newlines-in-powerbi/46705970#46705970)

To know more about UNICHAR()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dax/unichar-function-dax